# Performing a null check on itextsharp

Tags: java, itext

i want to test for a null value. i am using itextsharp to create a pdf. But i get an error saying, `(Redeundant toString());`the purpose of using the null check is to print out a value from two fields(ID Number/PassportNumber).

This is the line.

```
 Phrase phrase6 = new Phrase(client.getIdNumber() != null ? client.getIdNumber().toString() : "");
```

Comment: What is the type of IdNumber field? Please paste your complete error whatever you are getting

Comment: Sounds like some sort of code analyses "warning". What tool are you using? getIdNumber() probably already returns string.

Comment: PdfPCell b10 = new PdfPCell();
                Phrase phrase6 = new Phrase(client.getIdNumber() != null ? client.getIdNumber().toString() : "");
                phrase6.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
                b10.setColspan(6);
                Paragraph p13 = new Paragraph("ID Number/PassportNumber :");
                p13.add(phrase6);
                b10.addElement(p13);
                tbl.addCell(b10);

Comment: the idNumber is of type String. please help. how perform the null check

Comment: client.getIdNumber() !=null ? client.getPassportNo()

Comment: both passport number and Id number fields are of type String. help